# How to simplify quotient modules in homology computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute a homology group with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, which I know has result $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

So far I have gotten $$
H_1 = \frac{\langle a+c,b+c \rangle}{\langle b-a+c, a-b+c\rangle}
$$
and I am unsure how to simplify from here, or if this result can even simplify into the answer I want (perhaps I made a mistake earlier in the calculation).

What types of changes can I make to simplify this expression?

Comment: I suggest rewriting your basis vectors: use the basis $(x,y,z)=(a+c,b+c,c)$. Note though that your denominator is (as far as I can tell) not a subgroup of your numerator…

Comment: What are $a$, $b$ and $c$? I’d assume that these are elements of some abelian group (basis elements of $ℤ^3$ maybe?). But in an arbitrary abelian group, the denominator won’t be a subgroup of the numerator.

Comment: While this seems sorted, in general though, Smith Normal Form is your best friend for simplifying abelian group quotients :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give the context, but I assume this is the real projective plane's simplicial homology computation. Your description of the homology group is incorrect (the numerator and denominator should both be different).

Using the semisimplicial set with two $0$-simplices $v,w$, three $1$-simplices $a,b,c$ and two $2$-simplices $\alpha,\beta$ with defined boundaries: $$\partial\alpha=(b,a,c),\partial \beta=(a,b,c),\,\partial a=(v,w)=\partial b,\,\partial c=(w,w)$$

The realisation of (the free simplicial set associated to) this data is homeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^2$.

You have only a few maps of interest in the integer simplicial chain complex: $$C_2\to C_1\to C_0$$The map $C_3\to C_2$ has trivial image and $C_0\to 0$ has full kernel. In $C_2\to C_1$, the image will be: $$\operatorname{span}(b-a+c,a-b+c)\le\operatorname{span}(a,b,c)$$

Notice that $n(b-a+c)+m(a-b+c)=(n-m)(b-a)+(n+m)c$ and as $n,m$ vary arbitrarily we can actually let the coefficients $(n-m),(n+m)$ be any two integers **with the same parity**. Say $\sigma,\tau\in\Bbb Z$ have the same parity. Then $\sigma-\tau$ is even, so I can put $m:=\frac{\sigma-\tau}{2}$ as an integer as well as $n:=\frac{\sigma+\tau}{2}$ as an integer: $\sigma=n+m,\tau=n-m$ as desired (we can obtain $\sigma(b-a)+\tau c$ in the image). Conversely you just observe $n+m$ and $n-m$ have the same parity as they differ by $2m$.

So the image can be described as: $$\{m(b-a)+kc:k\equiv m\bmod2\}$$

The kernel of $C_1\to C_0$ is the set of all $na+mb+kc$ with $n(v-w)+m(v-w)+k(w-w)=(n+m)(v-w)=0$, so $n=-m$ is forced and $k$ is arbitrary. The kernel is then the span of $m(b-a)+kc$ where $m,k$ are arbitrary integers.

Compare that description with the image of $C_2\to C_1$. In the quotient kernel/image, consider that any $m(b-a)+kc$ is equivalent to $(k-m')c$ for any $m'$ with the same parity as $m$, by subtracting $m(b-a)+m'c$ (which is in the image). We can let $m'$ be $m+2k'$ for any $k'$ and depending on whether or not $(k-m)$ is even or odd, by varying $k'$ one finds an equivalence with $c=1\cdot c$ ($k-m$ is odd) or with zero ($k-m$ is even). The cosets are then representable as $[c]$ or as $[0]$, so there are at most two distinct cosets. It's straightforward to see that $[c]\neq[0]$, hence the quotient is exactly the two-element group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

That gives $H_1(\Bbb RP^2)\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. The kernel of $C_2\to C_1$ is all $n\alpha+m\beta$ with $n(b-a+c)+m(a-b+c)=0$, meaning $(n-m)(b-a)+(n+m)c=0$ so both $n-m$ and $n+m$ are zero. It follows $n=m=0$, so the kernel is trivial. Hence $H_2(\Bbb RP^2)=0$. Finally the image of $C_1\to C_0$ is merely the span of $(v-w)$ so $H_0(\Bbb RP^2)\cong\Bbb Z$ is easy to see.